# Why view updates incorrectly in my Ionic 2 app?

Tags: angular, view, android-camera, ionic2

I have issue with updating of my view depending on ngIf and `CameraPreview` plugin.

**HTML:**

```
<img *ngIf="taken" src="{{picture}}" />

  <ion-fab (click)="onPictureView(true)" top left bottom small *ngIf="taken">
    <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-fab (click)="onPictureView(false)" top right bottom small *ngIf="taken">
    <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-fab (click)="takePicture()" center bottom small *ngIf="!taken">
    <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
```

**TS:**

*in Constructor:*

```
CameraPreview.setOnPictureTakenHandler().subscribe((result) => {

        this.taken = true;
        this.toggleBackground('background-color: #ffffff !important;');
        alert(this.taken);

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///'+result[0], (fileEntry: any) => {
          fileEntry.file((file) => {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event:any) => {
              this.picture = event.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });
        });
      });
```

*class's methods*

```
  takePicture(){
    CameraPreview.takePicture();
  };

  onPictureView(value: boolean) {
    this.toggleBackground('background-color: transparent !important;');

    if (value) {

      if (this.counter < this.total - 1) {
        this.counter += 1;
        this.picTheme = this.section['photo' + (this.counter + 1)];
      }
      else {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
      }
    }
    this.taken = false;
  };
```

Initially `taken` is set to false so when user open preview he sees button with camera icon. But when he press it only background chages, but nor buttons switch niether image appears. However, if he press camera icon second time then buttons switch and picture appears. Alert works only first time. I can understand what's going on, why view isn't updated at first time and is at second one.

Comment: you should place plugin calls within platform.ready().then(()=>{})

Comment: @suraj I thought that I should call platform.ready() only in my app component, and this one is just one of my app's pages.

Comment: it needs to be within platform.ready

Comment: @suraj I've just wrapped calls from constructor and from `takePicture` in `platform.ready` but still see this strange behavior. I take several pictures in a row in my app and I see this behavior for each. It just feels like view isn't updated from the first time and I can't get why.

Comment: Perhaps a .detectChanges() would help?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Yeh, thanks, that's worked) Still curious why it didn't detected changes without it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases Angular can't/doesn't detect changes. ( I personally encounter this a lot when working with images) To force Angular to do a ngDoCheck(), use the following code.

```
import { ChangeDetectionRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public chRef: ChangeDetectionRef) {

}

yourFunction() {
  this.chRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Good luck !